# What unit of time does timeit return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, timeit

I don't know how to interpret the output from Python's timeit.timeit() function. My code is as follows:

```
import timeit

setup = """
import pydash
list_of_objs = [
    {},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 0: 0},
    {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'p': lambda x: x}
]
"""
print(timeit.timeit("pydash.filter_(list_of_objs, {'a': 1})", setup=setup))
```

The output from this is `11.85382745500101`. How do I interpret this number?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The return value is *seconds as a float*.

It is the *total time taken* to run the test (not counting the setup), so the average time per test is that number divided by the `number` argument, which defaults to 1 million.

See the [`Time.timeit()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit):

> Time *number* executions of the main statement. This executes the setup statement once, and then **returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float**. The argument is the number of times through the loop, defaulting to one million.

Comment: So this means that it is better to `repeat` 1e6 times with a `number` of 1 and take the minimum (implied by the docs)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no. Because then you are enabling and disabling the garbage collector a million times too. Do not set `number` to 1.