I'm using %%timeit in jupyter notebooks to get the execution time of my cell
whenever I run the cell the time is coming in microseconds, I want the time in seconds how can I achieve this?
enter image description here
I want time in seconds or how can I get the result in another time parameter like second or minute

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32058758/2836621

documentation for %%timeit shows that you can use -o  and it will return value which you can assign to variable and later you can use it to calculate seconds - but still don't  I know how to assign result to variable because variable = %%timeit -o doesn't work

Please do not use screenshots to provice code, please provide code and output directly in the question.

Doc for %timeit
If you put code in def function() then you can use %time (with single %)
with option -o function() to get result in variable
variable = %time -o function()

It doesn't work with double %%. It raises error when it sees %% after =.
For example (all in one cell)
def function():
    for x in range(1_000_000):
        x**2

variable = %timeit -o function()

print(f'{variable.average:.3} s')

But it still displays original result before your print()

EDIT:
for %% you can get result in _ in next cell
%%timeit -o
for x in range(1_000_000):
    x**2

next cell
print(f'{_.average:.3} s')

But it still displays original result before first cell
You can use %%capture to hide original result
%%capture
%%timeit -o
for x in range(1_000_000):
    x**2


Based on documentation for %%capture you can even use it to assign output to variable but it will be string, not object with .average, so it will be hard to format it. And it doesn't work for me :/
%%capture original_output
%%timeit -o
for x in range(1_000_000):
    x**2

next cell
print(f'{_.average:.3} s')
print(f'original output: {original_output}')


If you use print( dir(variable) ) then you see what other values you can get from variable and you can use them to format output on your own.
To skip names which start with _ (like __class__) you can use list comprehension:
[var for var in dir(variable) if not var.startswith('_')]

['all_runs',
 'average',
 'best',
 'compile_time',
 'loops',
 'repeat',
 'stdev',
 'timings',
 'worst']


EDIT:
Here notebook on nbviewer.org created by @Wayne (see comment below).
To make sure I add also screenshot:


I can help you with the captured output you get from %%capture. IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO it makes is  detailed here. I expanded on what you had when you said ,"And it doesn't work for me :/" at the too of this notebook here. Feel free to add it, if it helps.

@Wayne thanks, I already saw this doc. But probably I mess too much in cells in jupyter :) Maybe if I would restart all cell then it would work correctly - but I was already working on answer to other questions on Stackoverflow :) I will add link to your notebook.
